# Do I need Turkish transit visa to visit Northern Cyprus?

Tags: northern-cyprus

I am a Palestinian citizen living in lebanon. I am a student (aircraft engineer) in university of balamand and i basically have a paper that confirms this. My question is do i need a visa to enter North Cyprus on easter vacation for like maximum 6 days?last time i traveled with visa but I entered turkey for one day because there was a problem in aircraft so i slept one day in Istanbul which I entered turkey with this visa.in addition, last time i applied  visa to turkey but now i dont have this visa. Therefore,I booked tickets to Northern Cyprus im afraid they wont let me reach ercan because some offices told me i need transit turkish visa. I took ticket transit to adana to reach ercan. I have many friends with my case reached but im afraid.I hope u now understood my explanation.

Comment: It is not quite clear to me how your present plan differs from your successful trip last time. Can you edit your question to explain more details for us?

Comment: https://mfa.gov.ct.tr/consular-info/visa-regulations/ seems to say that you do not need a visa.

Comment: @mkennedy All flights to Northern Cyprus go through Turkey, so OP is asking if they need a Turkish transit visa. There are no direct international flights from any other country

Comment: @BritishSam Oops, missed that. Thanks!